# popup once in a day using jquery or php

Tags: php, jquery

How to show a FB likebox once in a day using jquery or php.And i have done with pop up and i want to save session or cookie in a browser.So that i can make the things working.Currently i am using jquery and php.

```
<body onload="openOffersDialog();">
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
<?php 
    if(!isset($_SESSION['jquery_popup']))  
    { 
    $_SESSION['jquery_popup'] = "sessionexists";

        echo $_SESSION['jquery_popup'];


    ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function openOffersDialog() {
    $('#overlay').fadeIn('fast', function() {
        $('#boxpopup').css('display','block');
        $('#boxpopup').animate({'left':'30%'},500);
    });
}


function closeOffersDialog(prospectElementID) {
    $(function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#' + prospectElementID).css('position','absolute');
            $('#' + prospectElementID).animate({'left':'-100%'}, 500, function() {
                $('#' + prospectElementID).css('position','fixed');
                $('#' + prospectElementID).css('left','100%');
                $('#overlay').fadeOut('fast');
            });
        });
    });
}
</script>

<div id="overlay" class="overlay"></div>
<!--<a onclick="openOffersDialog();">Click Here To See The PopUp</a>-->
<div id="boxpopup" class="box">

    <a onclick="closeOffersDialog('boxpopup');" class="boxclose"></a>
    <div id="content">

    <h2>Like us on Facebook</h2>
    <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fkornerseat&amp;width&amp;height=290&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;header=true&amp;stream=false&amp;show_border=true&amp;appId=474663095902746" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:290px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

    </div>
</div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would wanna use a cookie, simple set it to die after 24 hours and then check if it has expired if it has you show the popup again

**//Javascript version example taken from http://www.w3schools.com/**

```
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays)
{
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime()+(exdays*24*60*60*1000));
var expires = "expires="+d.toGMTString();
document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

function getCookie(cname)
{
var name = cname + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) 
  {
  var c = ca[i].trim();
  if (c.indexOf(name)==0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
  }
return "";
}
if(getCookie('jquery_popup') ==""){
setCookie('jquery_popup','sessionexists',1);
//Add code to display popup here
}
```

**PHP Method**

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['jquery_popup'])){
setcookie("jquery_popup", 'sessionexists', time()+3600*24); 
//Add code to display popup here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your fb Like button in the php code the way you have done before

```
<?php 
  if(!isset($_SESSION['jquery_popup']))  
  { 
    $_SESSION['jquery_popup'] = "sessionexists";
    echo '<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fkornerseat&amp;width&amp;height=290&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;header=true&amp;stream=false&amp;show_border=true&amp;appId=474663095902746" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:290px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>';
  }
?>
```

**Note**: Assuming that you are not destroying your session variable before.

Comment: The pop up is coming for second time i dont need it for the second time.Once in a 24 hours.is der any way to set using jquery

Comment: @user2959949: Then use cookie. And based on the cookie just add the iframe on the page.